# Optimum Serializing in Django Rest Framework and parsing in Javascript

Tags: json, django, rest, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to adapt an event calendar vuejs module called [dayspan](https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/dayspan-vuetify) calendar. Current entry object for an event as json is a bit strange and I want to balance the parsing of the payload before the post request and handling of data in DRF serializers. So I can get an optimum and performant client-server rest API communication. Json output is as below before any parsing:

```
{
  "data": {
    "title": "YOK",
    "description": "",
    "location": "",
    "color": "#1976d2",
    "forecolor": "#ffffff",
    "calendar": "",
    "busy": true,
    "icon": ""
  },
  "schedule": {
    "times": [
      "17"
    ],
    "dayOfMonth": [
      11
    ],
    "year": [
      2021
    ],
    "month": [
      5
    ]
  }
}
```

There are more schedule fields like "dayOFWeek", "duration" etc. that is to be expected for different entries.

What would be the best approach in terms of parsing json payload before posting to DRF and in deserializing stage before saving into database? I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Wouldn't it be fine to just you a model serialized that you can use to validate the request?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am asking more for the expertise because I've had issues before when I serialize-deserialize everything in backend or frontend. I was asking for the best practices in a rest API application for this case.